# sshpass will not run provided command on Ubuntu remote host when script is sourced, but does run on windows and if run within the same script

Tags: linux, bash, function, powershell, sshpass

I've searched on here for a bit and can't find someone who is going through this issue.

I have a tool/script I am building that uses sshpass to login to a remote host and pull logs, restart, etc... If I run the function within the main script it runs with no issues. If I source the script with the function, then it runs well if its accessing a windows IOT Core remote host, but will not execute commands if the remote host is linux.

**My device:**
Macbook Pro 2018
macOs Mojave 10.14.2

**Application**
Terminal

Here's what works:

**mainFile.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

function pullWindowsLog {
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@0.0.0.0 <<EOF
powershell.exe
Get-Content  c:\Path\To\Log\Log.log -tail 10
EOF
}

function pullLinuxLog {
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@0.0.0.0 <<EOF
echo 'password' | sudo -S docker logs --tail 10 container
EOF
}



function mainMenu {
    local PS3="What would you like to do?"
    local options=("Pull Windows Log" "Pull Linux Logs" "Quit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "Pull Windows Log")
                pullWindowsLog
                ;;
            "Pull Linux Logs")
                pullLinuxLog
                ;;
            "Quit")
                clear
                break
                ;;
            *) echo "\ninvalid option \n";;
        esac
    done
}

mainMenu
```

**Output:**

```
1) Pull Windows Log
2) Pull Linux Logs
3) Quit


What would you like to do?1 # <- user input

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Microsoft Windows [Version 0.0.0.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

user@WindowsDevice C:\Data\Users\User>powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Data\Users\User> Get-Content  c:\Path\To\Log\Log.log -tail 10
00:00:00.0000 Log line 1
00:00:00.0000 Log line 2
00:00:00.0000 Log line 3
00:00:00.0000 Log line 4
00:00:00.0000 Log line 5
00:00:00.0000 Log line 6
00:00:00.0000 Log line 7
00:00:00.0000 Log line 8
00:00:00.0000 Log line 9
00:00:00.0000 Log line 10

PS C:\Data\Users\User>

What would you like to do?2 # <- user input

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Welcome to Ubuntu 00.00.00 

  System information as of Day Mon  0 00:00:00 xxx Year

  System load:  0.00               Users logged in:             0
  Usage of /:   00.0% of 00.00GB   IP address for eth0:         00.00.00.00
  Memory usage: 00%                IP address for eth1:         00.00.00.00
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for eth2:         00.00.00.00
  Processes:    000

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

[sudo] password for user:

00:00:00.0000 Log line 1
00:00:00.0000 Log line 2
00:00:00.0000 Log line 3
00:00:00.0000 Log line 4
00:00:00.0000 Log line 5
00:00:00.0000 Log line 6
00:00:00.0000 Log line 7
00:00:00.0000 Log line 8
00:00:00.0000 Log line 9
00:00:00.0000 Log line 10

What would you like to do?3 # <- user input
```

What I would prefer, but is not working:

**MainFile.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

source pullWindowsLog.sh
source pullLinuxLog.sh

function mainMenu {
    local PS3="What would you like to do?"
    local options=("Pull Windows Log" "Pull Linux Logs" "Quit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "Pull Windows Log")
                pullWindowsLog
                ;;
            "Pull Linux Logs")
                pullLinuxLog
                ;;
            "Quit")
                clear
                break
                ;;
            *) echo "\ninvalid option \n";;
        esac
    done
}

mainMenu
```

**pullWindowsLog.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

function pullWindowsLog {
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@0.0.0.0 <<EOF
powershell.exe
Get-Content  c:\Path\To\Log\Log.log -tail 10
EOF
}
```

**pullLinuxLog.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

function pullLinuxLog {
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@0.0.0.0 <<EOF
echo 'password' | sudo -S docker logs --tail 10 container
EOF
}
```

Output:

```
1) Pull Windows Log
2) Pull Linux Logs
3) Quit


What would you like to do?1 # <- user input

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Microsoft Windows [Version 0.0.0.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

user@WindowsDevice C:\Data\Users\User>powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Data\Users\User> Get-Content  c:\Path\To\Log\Log.log -tail 10
00:00:00.0000 Log line 1
00:00:00.0000 Log line 2
00:00:00.0000 Log line 3
00:00:00.0000 Log line 4
00:00:00.0000 Log line 5
00:00:00.0000 Log line 6
00:00:00.0000 Log line 7
00:00:00.0000 Log line 8
00:00:00.0000 Log line 9
00:00:00.0000 Log line 10

PS C:\Data\Users\User>

What would you like to do?2 # <- user input

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

What would you like to do?3 # <- user input
```

For anyone concerned with security, I do not have any passwords hardcoded in the script. I just wrote it this way for the question. I am not having issues with passing variables, just how sshpass is acting when being sourced. I don't understand why there would be a difference on the remote host OS, but it is the only thing that is different. I tried running just an `ls` or `echo` and nothing. I also tried `sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@0.0.0.0 <command>` and didnt even get a `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`. As you can see in the first output, the linux system information is loaded. This is not happening in the second output.

I understand that I could just have everything in one script, but I am hoping to expand on this tool and would rather just add a menu item when the tool is ready. Also keeping the environment clean will allow me to easily pass this on to someone else to expand.

I hope I provided enough information (probably TMI at this point) for some terminal genius to figure this out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I feel like I should have known this, but somehow it slipped my mind. I had to add `-t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` on sshpass. so the command should be

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "user@0.0.0.0" <<EOF
echo 'password' | sudo -S docker logs --tail 10 container
EOF
```

Hopefully someone finds this and it helps them.